# error while calling dependent file

Tags: java

i created 2 files... namely Shirt.java and ShirtTest.java

The code for the Shirt.java class is as follows--

```
public class Shirt{
public int ShirtID=0;
public String description="-description required-";
public char colorCode='U';
public double price=0.0;
public int quantityInStock=0;


public void displayShirtInformation(){
    System.out.println("ShirtId:"+ShirtID);
    System.out.println("ShirtDescription"+description);
    System.out.println("Color Code:"+colorCode);
    System.out.println("Shirt Price"+price);
    System.out.println("Quantity In Stock"+quantityInStock);


}

}
```

The code for the ShirtTest.java is as follows--

```
public class ShirtTest {

  public static void main (String args[]) {

  Shirt myShirt = new Shirt();

  myShirt.displayShirtInformation();

  } 
}
```

While i compiled the Shirt.java file.. it compiled with no errors and created a Shirt.class
file.. but when i tried to compile the ShirtTest file.. it gave an error..
Which is as follows..

```
> C:\java>javac ShirtTest.java
ShirtTest.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Shirt
location: class ShirtTest
  Shirt myShirt = new Shirt();
  ^
ShirtTest.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Shirt
location: class ShirtTest
  Shirt myShirt = new Shirt();
                      ^
2 errors
```

What is the problem here?

p.s-both Shirt.java as well as ShirtTest.java are in the same folder

Comment: Is your current directory in your classpath?

Comment: Are the two classes in the same package?

Comment: @patapizza- any way to check weather the current directory is in the classpath?

Comment: @james-Well the 2 classes are in the same folder, if that's what you ment byasking if they are in the same package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `javac Shirt.java`
Then: `javac ShirtTest.java`
After that you can run `ShirtTest` like that: `java ShirtTest`

Comment: ya.. i tried that but the second file ShirtTest does not compile .. and it gives the above mentioned error message

Comment: Then try this: `javac -cp . Shirt.java ShirtTest.java`

Comment: @cldy- will i have to do this every time?? any way to make this simple??

Comment: You have to set your `classpath`. I see that mikej is already answered this question. Also I suggest you to use some IDE - Eclipse, Netbeans and you won't need to compile manually.

Comment: @cldy-Thanks.. i'll look into it..   P.s-By the way.. even when i run it on netbeans.. the error pops us.. anyway.. i'll figure it out THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your classes in packages.  Using the default package is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the current directory is in the classpath when compiling the test. e.g.

```
javac -cp . ShirtTest.java
```

You can check the current classpath with

```
c:\java> set CLASSPATH
```

When you compile Shirt.java it doesn't have any dependencies outside of the core Java libraries so the classpath doesn't matter for that. That's why you only see a problem when you come to ShirtTest.java

Comment: @mike- it gave the output:CLASSPATH=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5     What does that mean???

Comment: @nav Take a look at the [Java tutorial section on classpaths](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). I'm not sure what's causing the *couldn't create JVM* error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile `Shirt` class?

Try :`javac Shirt.java ShirtTest.java`

Comment: but the problem still persists... whenever i compile ShirtTest.java .. the above mentioned errors sprout again!!  :(