# Problem While Setting up JAVA fro the 1st time on Windows 7

Tags: java

I installed the J2SE 6.o version.  Now I'm having a problem getting it to work right.

```
> C:\java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
```

This is the path of the bin file, and I put this in the Path tab.  In the environment settings.

What are the next steps that I have to take to run `.java` files from the command prompt?

Do I have to put something in the class-path tab too?

Let me elaborate my problem:

If I run and compile the below mentioned file called `Shirt.java` it works fine.

```
public class Shirt{
public int ShirtID=0;
public String description="-description required-";
public char colorCode='U';
public double price=0.0;
public int quantityInStock=0;


public void displayShirtInformation(){
    System.out.println("ShirtId:"+ShirtID);
        System.out.println("ShirtDescription"+description);
        System.out.println("Color Code:"+colorCode);
        System.out.println("Shirt Price"+price);
        System.out.println("Quantity In Stock"+quantityInStock);
    }
}
```

But if I run another file that calls the previous file, then problems crop up.
The file that calls the previous file is as follows.

```
public class ShirtTest {

  public static void main (String args[]) {

  Shirt myShirt = new Shirt();

  myShirt.displayShirtInformation();

  } 
}
```

When I try to execute the second file, there are a few errors that crop up and no compilation takes place.  I believe it  has something to do with some problem with the environment variable Path declaration.

Comment: You say there are errors, but you haven't said what they are. You say no compilation takes place, but presumably it's the compilation which is generating errors. You say you're trying to *execute* a file, but I suspect you mean you're trying to *compile* the file. You haven't told us how you've tried to compile, or where any of these files are. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please learn how to use the code formatting tools of SO.  To format some code (HTML, I/O etc.), select the code and click the `{}` button above the posting form.

Comment: BTW - how is this question different to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424458/error-while-calling-dependent-file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to make sure that you do *not* have a CLASSPATH environment variable set. If it is not set, Java will by default look in the current directory for class files. As long as your Java source files are in the same directory (and not in a package) you should be able to compile and run them with simple commands:

```
javac Shirt.java
javac ShirtTest.java
java ShirtTest
```

If this complains with a `NoClassDefFoundError`, then try specifying the classpath on the command line using the `-cp` option:

```
javac -cp . Shirt.java
javac -cp . ShirtTest.java
java -cp . ShirtTest
```

(note that `.` means "the current directory").

See the [Getting Started tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html), which also has a section on [common problems](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html) and their solutions.

When you get an error, please always copy & paste the exact error message, instead of just saying "I get some errors". The more specific information you give, the easier it is to understand what the exact problem it is and the better we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an IDE, this avoid the need to

- setup the path
- check that all the classes you need have been compiled.
- setup the classpath for the `java`

Instead all you need to do is hit the `Run` button and it does the rest.

It may even help you write/format the code and generate a toString() method, getters/setters  and unit tests for it.

Answer (score 0):

There can't be any problem with the path settings as the first java file is working, otherwise it would have given "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error.